# Nodemon to auto update changes to my script

Tags: javascript, nodemon

I am using [nodemon](/questions/tagged/nodemon)to auto update changes to my script.

Can I somehow add another file that i'd want to auto refresh.

```
    "scripts": {
      "start": "babel-node ./server/index.js",
      "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx",
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node ./server/index.js"
    },
```

I would like to add `./views/index.js` to the "`dev`" script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create a nodemon.json file and have it read the config from there. Example:

```
{
  "restartable": "rs",
  "ignore": [
    "test/*",
  ],
  "exec": "ts-node ./src/index.ts",
  "watch": [
    "src",
    "config"
  ],
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development"
  },
  "ext": "ts js json"
}
```

Look at the "watch" property, also the "ignore". Then you simply run `nodemon` to start up.